# macos iterm2 tmux remap ctrl-b to right option/alt-a

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I thought this was a no brainer. I am using tmux with iterm2 (latest version) on maxOs on a MacBook.

Using ctrl-b as prefix is a terrible key combination for a MacBook, since the MacBook has only one control key, which is placed on the left hand side. So pressing these two buttons at the same time is almost painful for me. But tmux is awesome, so it lets you remap the prefix.

So, quite naively, I entered this line into my **~/.tmux.conf** in order to set the prefix to option/alt-a:

```
set-option -g prefix M-a
```

However, that line didn't change a thing.

Entering **tmux show-options -g** still outputs

```
prefix C-b
```

Has anyone ever solved this?

BTW: I know I could use iterm2's tmux integration. But I don't want that. I want a plain text mode solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, so I found a solution:

```
  1 # change ctrl-a to alt-a
  2 unbind C-b
  3 set-option -g prefix M-a
  4 bind C-a send-prefix
```

And then in iterm2 -> profiles -> [your profile] > Keys

for **Right Option/Alt Key**

click **Esc+**

I'm sorry. I found this solution, after having posted the question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with your solution !

Comment: Why don't you mark it as answer? It works perfectly!

Comment: @Farzad I had totally forgotten about this. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @LongHike glad that I could help 